# Install dependencies for Geany on Windows

Tags: windows, geany

I'd like to find a way to automatically install the dependencies for Geany (which has all its dependencies installed automatically on Ubuntu, when installed from the Ubuntu software center) Is it possible to do this on Windows as well?

Comment: This question sort of makes no sense for me: If its all automatically installed, what dependencies do you need?

Comment: In my case, I want to be able to compile Java, C, Python, and C++ files from Geany.

Comment: Also, I fixed the typo that led to this ambiguity. I hope the question makes more sense now.

Comment: So... you want it to download and install MSVC for you?

Comment: No, I'm not using Microsoft Visual C++. I'm using Geany, as stated in the title.

Comment: Is MSVC one of the dependencies of the Windows version of Geany? Also, is it possible to automatically install all of Geany's dependencies using some kind of Windows package manager?

Comment: It's a C/C++ compiler. It's used to compile C and C++ programs, which is one of the goals you've stated.